# How to select specific version of python when embeding python in application

Tags: python, c

I am trying to embed python into an application written in C. I would like for the user to choose which version of python they would like to run the application with by specifying it as a command link argument.

Like the following:

```bash
myapplication --use python3.9
```

I am using the [Stable Application Binary Interface](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/stable.html#stable), but if I link with `python3` using the following command I get the following error.

```bash
❯ clang -L/usr/lib -I/usr/include/python3.9 -lpython3 ./myapplication.c -o ./myapplication
/bin/ld: /tmp/myapplication-e0dac8.o: undefined reference to symbol 'Py_Initialize'
/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython3.11.so.1.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If I link with a specific version of python, using the following command

```bash
clang -L/usr/lib -I/usr/include/python3.9 -lpython3.9 ./myapplication.c -o ./myapplication
```

It compiles without any errors. But now other versions of python will not work with it.